# Synchronize DateLastModified not reading correctly MS Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

When comparing two MS Access databases, the fso.DateLastModified property is not returning the information I expect.

I have a database called "Crosswalk Engine."  When I make changes to the one on "SharedHome", I expect the "LocalWorkingPath" to get the changes, but it already shows that the files are the same, so it never gets the update.  I have confirmed in a message box that LocalWorkingPath and SharedHome are different as you can see in the code.  Yet, DateLastModified always returns that they are identical.  Obviously, I set something incorrectly, but I can't find it:

```
Public Sub SyncFundingAndCrosswalk()


    Dim fso As Object


    Dim CWLocal As Object
    Dim CWServer As Object 
    Dim strCW As String


    strCW = "Crosswalk_Engine.accdb"

    Dim strSQL As String

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If fso.FileExists(LocalWorkingPath) Then
        'Do nothing if the LocalWorkingPath exists
    Else
        ensurePath (LocalWorkingPath)

        Call UpdateStatusScreen("Getting crosswalk")
        Call copyDB(SharedHome, strCW, LocalWorkingPath)

    End If

    Set CWServer = fso.getfile(SharedHome & "\" & strCW)
    Set CWLocal = fso.getfile(LocalWorkingPath & "\" & strCW)


        MsgBox "Crosswalk on server: " & CWServer.DateLastModified & vbCr & "Path: " & SharedHome & "\" & strCW & _
              "Crosswalk on Local: " & CWLocal.DateLastModified & " Path: " & LocalWorkingPath & "\" & strCW

        If CWServer.DateLastModified > CWLocal.DateLastModified Then
         Call PopUpMsg("Getting changes to crosswalk...", "Crosswalk changed")
         Call copyDB(SharedHome, strCW, LocalWorkingPath)
            MsgBox "Crosswalk files are now current"

        Else
            MsgBox "Crosswalk files remain current.", vbInformation

        End If


End Sub
```

Comment: `.DateLastModified` just returns the `Date modified` property as set in Windows. Are those the same? There are many ways to change a file without touching that property.

Comment: If I delete or edit a record in a table in the database shouldn’t it be modified?

Comment: Nope, it's updated when the last user closes the database. It's not continuously changed for every change in the database. Also, it's changed when a user opens and closes the database due to locking, even if that user changes nothing.

Comment: Each user does in fact cause that to happen between usage of the database. Should I approach this differently even though I see that the last modified property in windows changed? If so, how?

Comment: How to approach this is too broad of a question. I'd personally never store data twice, and just use linked tables. Replication is another option, but that's deprecated since Access 2013.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth to clarify, I agree. Most of the database are linked tables.  However, I successfully managed to speed up the database by making two of the linked tables local. I.e., these local tables (Which are locally linked) only get updated if there are actually changes in them on the server if a different user logs on.. So if only one user uses the database, it never needs to update.  For this example, I didn’t include the other linked table which is working as described. It is identical to my example.  I observe one user making changes in their FE and I actually get them in mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line above that reads

```
If fso.FileExists(LocalWorkingPath) then
```

should read

```
if fso.FolderExists(LocalWorkingPath) then
```

Basically, this was always returning false causing the server files to overwrite the local files and the date time stamps will then always match when the check is performed later.

Now, I can change a record in the database and the DateLastModified does in fact change.   -- Thanks James.